# ffmpeg error with spaces

Tags: java, ffmpeg, directory, whitespace

I have a video file in a directory, but there are spaces in the directory name so ffmpeg does process my input correctly. Is there a way to fix this or replace the space with something? Thanks for any help! I am using Runtime.exec() to execute ffmpeg.

Comment: ffmpeg perfectly manage path and filename having space, I suppose in your .exec call you missed that you must concatenate " around the file path variable.

Comment: Yes I did miss the " around the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. All I had to do was surround the filename with "".